# Optimizing web parsing with Beautifulsoup, Functions I don't know?

Tags: html, performance, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing, processing-efficiency

I have a multiprocessing loop which uses urllib and beautifulsoup to scan webpages for data, then I run if statements. Each process takes about 3 seconds to run. 2.95 of those seconds are spent getting the html, and the remainder is spent running ifs and cutting up the very small amount of data that I need.

The webpages consists of about 622 lines with something like 125,000 characters. I only need two or three lines and 200-300 characters. I am looking for a way to shorten the time this loop runs. Is there a function that will allow me to skip the first 500 lines of html? does anyone have other recommendations? for now I am using tags and attributes to determine what info I need, but if I could just say 'I want to read only lines 500-700' wouldnt that be faster?

given that the entire pool of multiprocesses takes nearly three minutes to run, any amount of time I can shave off will be helpful to me. Here's what I am using so far to pick apart the html.

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen(l[y]).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

for row in soup.html.body.find_all('table', attrs={'class':'table-1'}):
      for i,j in zip(row.find_all('a'), row.find_all('td', attrs={'width':'130', 'align':'right'})):
            >run ifs
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: First and main thing is to use asynchronous framework like [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)